# What to write in mail if someone asking to reply to confirm

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, formal-language, email

what to send in reply if someone asking to reply the mail to confirm

> As discussed, Please find the details below and kindly
>   confirm your presence by replying to this email.

I am thinking that it should be

Ok, Confirmed, I got it.. etc

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the responses you listed, “Confirmed” is the only one I might use. “OK” and “I got it” are too vague and only tell the other person you received the email. This sounds like a formal occasion given the polite language (“please”, “kindly”). So it might be a good idea to give a polite answer that is more than one word, like:

> Thank you. I am confirming my attendance.